# is there a way to programmatically determine if a repository is following gitflow?

Tags: git, github, gitlab, analytics, git-flow

so I'm working on a project that analyzes GitLab repositories, the task that is assigned to me right now is to find a way to determine if a GitLab repo is following Gitflow principles! I've looked on the web and it doesn't seem like there is a naming convention for the branches or a certain config or anything, should I try for example to analyze the repo activity to see if it resembles Gitflow or not? is there a better way to do so? thanks :)

Comment: Probably? List all branches and see if the standard gitflow branches exist? I’m also fairly confident that all branches should only share the root commit with master.

Comment: I don't think there's a reliable way to classify repositories in such a way.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a tool like `Jgit` and ask for git repo if you find:

- master branch
- develop branch (can not be the same as master
- prefixes branches? Features/ ..hotfix/...release/